# Question regarding the average of whole numbers, and whether said number can have decimal paces.

Tags: statistics

I am currently writing a Biology lab on populations of bacteria and measuring them by their growth rate. Essentially, I will conduct a set of 5 trails, finding the average final size of each population. Because I am measuring bacteria, I am measuring in whole numbers (there can't be 43.6 bacteria). But when I go to take the average of each set of trails, of course, I will get a value that has decimal places.

ex. [My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMLF0.png)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. Actual objects must be counted in whole numbers; but averages of counts are not themselves counts of actual objects, so there's no problem.

Example: In every at bat, a baseball player gets exactly 0 or 1 hits; but nobody bats (sorry) an eye when it's reported that they get 0.275 hits per at-bat on average.

Answer (score 0):

I also find myself writing lab reports from time to time that require taking the averages of desired populations. Even though your measurements are in whole numbers, which is correct when taking a head count, the average can be in decimal form since you are unlikely to get a perfect multiple. Since you are not providing a head count of one population, it is perfectly acceptable to present the average as a decimal. I would just make sure to clearly state that you took the average of 5 populations.